# Cabide ou cruzeta?

Tags: português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, sinônimos, uso-mais-comum

[Cabide](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/cabide/):

> vem do Árabe *qabda*, “garra, gancho”

[Cruzeta](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/cruzeta/):

> vem do Latim CRUX, “cruz”

Considerando este tipo de objeto:

[image: Cabide ou cruzeta]

Qual destas palavras é a mais comum em Portugal e no Brasil? Existem outras palavras equivalentes?

Por curiosidade, se *cruzeta* vem de *cruz*, existem cabides/cruzetas em forma de cruz?

Comment: Dê, uma olhada: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-diferenca-entre-cabide-e-cruzeta/22097

Comment: @tdmsoares boa referência, obrigado!

Comment: Nunca ouvi "cruzeta" no Brasil.  Mas também não vou ao Norte ou ao Nordeste com frequência.

Comment: Sendo "cabide" uma palavra de origem árabe e "cruzeta" de origem latina, esta última deveria ser comum no norte de Portugal e rara no sul.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse Link, em que alguns usuários postaram os diversos significados para esta palavra: http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/cruzeta/

Comment: @Armfoot A foto que o Jacinto postou tem um cabide em formato de cruz (cruzeta)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eu já tinha visto cabides em forma de cruz, não sabia era que se podiam chamar *cruzetas*. Segundo o [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/cruzeta), este nome é usado em Portugal e no Norte e Nordeste brasileiro. Eu sou da zona de Lisboa, e não conhecia a palavra. [Este artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-diferenca-entre-cabide-e-cruzeta/22097) diz que parece ser mais usado no norte.

[image]

Em coerência com o Aulete, a ocorrência mais recente de *cruzeta* neste Corpus do Português é numa obra duma cearense, [Rachel de Queiroz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_de_Queiroz), em [*Dôra, Doralina*](http://www.uel.br/pos/letras/EL/vagao/EL10C-Art8.pdf) (1975). E mais importante que a origem da autora é a protagonista, por cuja boca a história é contada, ser também cearense (ênfase minha):

> Sentada na cama, enquanto D. Loura desarrumava a minha mala (...) 0 telegrama anunciando a minha vinda apanhou D. Loura de surpresa, e surpresa maior ela teve quando eu disse que tinha vindo pra ficar. — Não agüentei mais, não agüentei, D. Loura. Acho que se eu ficasse mais tempo ali, morria também. Ela não fez demonstrações; ***pendurou na cruzeta o vestido*** que tinha na mão, chegou perto de mim, puxou minha cabeça para o seu colo e me deu um beijo no cabelo

E a confirmar a experiência do Artefacto (comentário abaixo), encontrei esta [*Vida e Mortes de Faustino Cavco*](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL24842632M/vida_e_mortes_de_faustino_cavaco), uma biografia do [infame algarvio assaltande de bancos](http://www.publico.pt/destaque/jornal/ladroes-violentos-num-pais-calmo-228492) (1989):

> A seguir mudou de táctica, conforme ia revistando, ia fazendo de mim ***cruzeta***. Encheu-me os braços de roupa, depois quando acabou disse-me: — Agora põe bem, se quiseres. Comecei a dobrar a roupa e a pô-la na mala.

Comment: Eu, de Lisboa, só ouvi a palavra de colegas da faculdade, mas do Sul (também não havia muita gente do Norte no meu curso).

Comment: Cruzeta era usado antigamente. Sou da zona do Algarve, e, por vezes, as pessoas com uma idade mais avançada, dizem cruzeta em vez de cabide. Pensei que fosse assim em todo o lado...

Comment: "Cum laude", como sempre.  +1

Comment: Dinah Silveira de Queiroz foi uma grande romancista.

Comment: @Centaurus, a referência está errada; não é primeira vez que acontece no Corpus do Português. Em *A Muralha* da Dinah Queiroz não havia telegramas. Poderá ser Rachel Queiroz, do Ceará!. Estou a investigar.

Comment: @Centaurus Está resolvido: é mesmo Rachel de Queiroz.

Comment: Haha, o Jacinto não conhecia uma palavra, olhem que ignorante! ;-p

Comment: Note-se que a cruzeta não tem de ser em formato de cruz, pelo menos segundo a minha experiência. Aquele pau vertical ao centro é, aliás, muito raro.

Comment: @ANeves, eu sou extraordinariamente ignorante (disfarço é muito bem). Pois, aquelas cruzetas em forma de cruz são de facto raras; tem aspeto de ser modelo antigo; eu já tinha visto, mas nem sei para que é que aquele pau vertical tão comprido serve. Para ajudar a pendurar num varão alto?

Answer (score 6):

Sou brasileiro e nunca ouvi falar de cruzeta para este objeto.

Chamamos aqui de *cabide* (pelo menos na região em que estou)

Cruzeta, é algo relativo ao formato de cruz.

Agora, como o Jacinto postou, há algumas regiões que chamam esse objeto para segurar roupas de *Cruzeta*.

De acordo com este site: [Enciclopédia - O Nordeste - Cruzeta](http://www.onordeste.com/onordeste/enciclopediaNordeste/index.php?titulo=Cruzeta&ltr=c&id_perso=6760),  no Norte e Nordeste do Brasil eles chamam de "Cruzeta", e de acordo com este mesmo site, há regiões do próprio nordeste brasileiro que chamam apenas de *Cruzeta* os cabides em forma de cruz

Comment: também nunca ouvi, mas segundo o Jacinto a palavra é usada no Norte e no Nordeste.  Eu sou do sudeste e portanto nem sempre posso responder sobre certos regionalismos.

Comment: Voce tem razão. Pelo que também pesquisei, em alguns estados do Norte e Nordeste, cruzeta tem o mesmo significado. Mas em alguns estados do Nordeste significa cabide em cruz para roupas. Daqui a pouco posto os links

Answer (score 1):

Vivo na região norte do BRASIL há 15 anos, especificamente no município de Santarém/PARÁ onde é notória a influência portuguesa na cultura e no linguajar...Para se ter uma idéia desta influência é bom lembrar que o PARÁ reconheceu a Independência do Brasil apenas em 15 de agosto de 1823, dia que os paraenses denominaram de 'O DIA DA ADESÃO". Alguns municípios da região de Santarém, no Oeste do Pará, prestam verdadeiras homenagens a Portugal ao adotarem nomes idênticos aos de cidades e vilas existentes naquele país ibérico: Óbidos, Alenquer, Almeirim, Alter do Chão, chamados de municípios irmãos, só para citar alguns. É natural que essa influência traga reflexos fortíssimos no vocabulário e no sotaque do PARAENSE, que sibila bastante na hora de pronunciar a letra "S" (tem som de SHHH). Aquí no norte do Brasil se utiliza muito, e de forma correta, a segunda pessoa, na hora de conjugar verbos. "Tú vais, tu vistes, tú queres, tú fostes" são expressões frequentes por aquí. "CRUZETA" é a forma corriqueira de nomear o utensílio para se pendurar roupas aquí no PARÁ. Absolutamente não está errado e não é um neologismo, mas sim um arcaísmo, de tão antiga que é essa palavra. Todo mundo sabe o que é, e poucos PARAENSES chamam esse objeto de cabide, termo de origem árabe, bem mais recente, e que significa "GANCHO". Descobrí que a palavra "CRUZETA", antiquíssima, é de origem latina, e mesmo em PORTUGAL está caindo em desuso, restrita ao português mais castiço, ainda cultivado na região norte do país. Em Lisboa os  mais jovens já não sabem do que se trata. Outro exemplo dessa influência está numa fruta deliciosa que se consome por aquí, com o nome de "GINJA". Ouví pela primeira vez em SANTARÉM (PARÁ)a palavra "GINJA", para denominar as pitangas que conhecemos no sul e sudeste do país.Muitos anos depois me reencontrei com esta palavra numa visita a LISBOA, para designar um delicioso licor de cerejas. Daí entendí o aportuguesamento das nossas pitangas, fruta tão próxima das cerejas portuguesas, em formato, côr e sabor. Acho fantástico encontrar no estado do PARÁ um reduto do bom e castiço português, e que ele possa sobreviver ao bombardeio de uma cultura globalizante, que há bem pouco tempo aportou por aquí.Tomara que os paraenses continuem porta-vozes de um DNA cultural bonito e necessário ao conhecimento de nossas próprias origens.